# Invalid file fontname in imagettftext()

Tags: php, codeigniter

i tried creating my own captcha library in code igniter, now the library is working fine without code igniter but when i included it with the code igniter it gave this message

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Warning
>
> Message: imagettftext(): Invalid font filename
>
> Filename: helpers/cap_helper.php
>
> Line Number: 13

`

```
//now my cap_helper.php looks like this
    header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
    function create_image($fontfile)
    {
        echo $fontfile;
        $text = rand(0,9999);
        $font_size = 30;
        $image_width = 200;
        $image_height = 40;
        $image = imagecreate($image_width,$image_height);
        imagecolorallocate($image, 255, 255, 255);
        $text_color = imagecolorallocate($image, 0, 0, 0);
        imagettftext($image, $font_size, 0, 15, 30, $text_color, $fontfile, $text);
        imagejpeg($image);
    }
//controller file looks like this
function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<div class="alert alert-danger">','</div>');
        $this->load->model(array('welcome_model'));
        $this->load->helper(array('cap'));
    }
    function testing()
    {
        echo '<img src="'.create_image(base_url().'assets/font.ttf').'"/>';
    }
```

`
now my font.ttf file is saved in appname/assets/font.ttf
what i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Try below code It's work for me

```
function testing(){
    echo '<img src="'.create_image(realpath('assets/font.ttf')).'"/>';
}
```

Comment: maybe you could explain a bit further what was the problem and why this works.

Comment: because font need actual path of font file not virtual path that's why is say Invalid font filename. Basically this problem occur in codeignitor & laravel

Answer (score 0):

I guess you'd better not use an url to locate your font, but an absolute path instead. So something like that :

```
function testing()
{
    echo '<img src="'.create_image('/assets/font.ttf').'"/>';
}
```